# calling web services created Geofences in android

Tags: android, android-geofence

I need to write a web service that will create the Geofence on Google maps and i have the client app(android)that when ever any user enters into that geofence(proximity) area then the client get the notification messages.

I have few questions

1.Is it possible to catch the geofence created in the server to client(android app)?

If possible how to do it ?